# Why does my EC2 AWS instance receive timeouts sending mails via postfix?

Tags: email, postfix, aws, amazon-ec2

I am trying to set up a postfix mailserver for outgoing mails on my EC2 instance.
Basically i do not understand why the server times out pinging external hosts:

1. Postfix is set up correctly and with a valid TLS certificate
2. AWS say they have removed the smtp blockage for EC2 instances which they use to prevent spam
3. All required ports should be open

I am still getting timeouts when trying to send mails, it is getting quiet frustrating:

[image: Console log of the mailq]

Any ideas on what i could be doing wrong here?

Comment: Is this EC2 instance in a public subnet of your VPC, and does the EC2 instance have a public or elastic IP address?

Comment: It does have an elastic ip address

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic about this detail, but I've made the mistake of associating an elastic IP address to an EC2 server that wasn't in a public subnet and couldn't use the address.  Is this EC2 server in a public subnet?

Comment: Yes it is. We gave up on the idea to use postfix ourselves now anyways, since AWS SES seems to be much more scalable.